# C++ - Reading int as sequence of letters and digits

Tags: c++

```
int number;
string text;

cin>>number;          // Here I read "1234aaaa"
cin>>text;

cout<<number<<" "<<text;      // It prints "1234 aaaa"
```

I understand that the stream stores `aaaa` from the previous reading and then it passes it to the next reading.

How can I avoid the garbage value from `number` to be passed to `text` ?

Comment: What output do you expect instead of `"1234 aaaa"`?

Comment: either "1234" or, eventually, to prompt for another input

Comment: It's not a "garbage value", an integer ends at the first non-digit character. If you want to ignore it, read it and throw it away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I avoid the garbage value from number to be passed to text ?

All depends on what you want exactly

If you want to flush all the rest of the line after the number you can use `getline` :

```
std::string s;
std::getline(std::cin, s);
```

but to save in a string is useless, so you can do also :

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

that removes all after the number whatever you input  `1234aaaa`or `1234 aaaa bbbb` or just the possible newline after `1234`

---

If you just want to read a *word* (without spaces inside) and extract the number at its beginning you can do

```
std::string text;

if (std::cin >> text) {
  std::stringstream ss(text);
  int number;

  if (ss >> number) {
    ...something using number...
  }
  else {
    .. error no valid integer...
  }
}
else {
  ...EOF
}
```

in that case if the input is `1234aaaa bbbb` you extract `1234` and flush `aaaa` but `bbbb` or anything after `1234aaaa`is still available to be read

Answer (score 1):

You may use a temporary string to consume all input, and then convert

```
int number;
string text;
string tmp;

cin>>tmp;          // Here I read "1234aaaa"
number = stoi(tmp);
cin>>text;

cout<<number<<" "<<text;
```

Comment: by pity do not use `atoi` in an answer (also in C)